# Get content of an ArrayCollection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, arraycollection

I would like to upgrade my symfony 2 project from 2.3 to 2.7 LTS version. I have a problem in a repository to get result of a query. In 2.3, this query give me something :

```
    public function findProtectedPublications( $steps, $start, $end)
    {

        $query= $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('d.pubRefs')
        ->from('ImpressionDemandBundle:Event', 'h')
        ->innerJoin('h.demand','d')
        ->where('d.protectedPublications = :pub')
        ->setParameter('pub', 1 )   
        ->andWhere('h.date >= :start')
        ->setParameter('start', $start )
        ->andWhere('h.date <= :end')
        ->setParameter('end', $end )
        ->andWhere('h.stepId in (:steps)')
        ->setParameter('steps', $steps )
        ->orderBy('d.id','ASC')
        ->getQuery();

        $results = $query->getResult();
        $publications = array();
        if ($results && ! empty ($results)){
            foreach($results as $result){
                $pubs = $result['pubRefs'];
                if ($pubs && ! empty($pubs)){
                    foreach($pubs as $pub){
                        $publications[] = $pub;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return  $publications;

    }
```

But this code doesn't work in earlier version because $pubs variable in an ArrayCollection. So I changed the end of my code with this :

```
    $results = $query->getResult();           
        $publications = array();
        if ($results && ! empty ($results)){
                    foreach($results as $result){
                        $pubs = $result['pubRefs'];
                        var_dump($pubs);
                        if (! $pubs->isEmpty()){
                            $arrayPubs = $pubs->toArray();
                            foreach($arrayPubs as $pub){
                $publications[] = $pub;
                            }
                        }
                    }
        }

        return  $publications;
```

In this part, when I dump the $pubs variable, I have :

```
    object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)#131 (2) {
  ["elements":"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":private]=>
  NULL
  ["_elements":"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":private]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(Impression\DemandBundle\Entity\Publication)#125 (5) {
      ["editor":"Impression\DemandBundle\Entity\Publication":private]=>
      string(24) "Journal Le Monde 4-10-13"
      ["coauthors":"Impression\DemandBundle\Entity\Publication":private]=>
      string(12) "Machin Machin"
      ["title":"Impression\DemandBundle\Entity\Publication":private]=>
      string(57) "La tragédie de Lampedusa: s"émouvoir, comprendre, agir."
      ["nbPages":"Impression\DemandBundle\Entity\Publication":private]=>
      float(1)
      ["nbCopies":"Impression\DemandBundle\Entity\Publication":private]=>
      float(40)
    }
  }
}
```

So it seems that there are elements in this ArrayCollection, but the test $pubs->isEmpty() gives a true result, so I have nothing in $publications array.

Edit: In fact, the problem seems to be due to my data in the database : for an object previous from my upgrade, I have something like this in the database :

```
O:43:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":1:{s:54:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection_elements";a:1:{i:0;O:42:"Impression\DemandBundle\Entity\Publication":5:{s:50:"Impression\DemandBundle\Entity\Publicationeditor";s:5:"BREAL";s:53:"Impression\DemandBundle\Entity\Publicationcoauthors";s:5:"MONOT";s:49:"Impression\DemandBundle\Entity\Publicationtitle";s:18:"USA Canada mexique";s:51:"Impression\DemandBundle\Entity\PublicationnbPages";d:150;s:52:"Impression\DemandBundle\Entity\PublicationnbCopies";d:150;}}}
```

and this gives the error.
For a object add after my upgrade, I have something like this in the database :

```
O:43:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":1:{s:53:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollectionelements";a:1:{i:0;O:42:"Impression\DemandBundle\Entity\Publication":5:{s:50:"Impression\DemandBundle\Entity\Publicationeditor";s:8:"dfg dfgd";s:53:"Impression\DemandBundle\Entity\Publicationcoauthors";s:7:"dfg dfg";s:49:"Impression\DemandBundle\Entity\Publicationtitle";s:5:"fdg d";s:51:"Impression\DemandBundle\Entity\PublicationnbPages";d:5;s:52:"Impression\DemandBundle\Entity\PublicationnbCopies";d:3;}}}
```

and the function findProtectedPublications() works without errors.

The difference between the two versions is ArrayCollection_elements for the first and ArrayCollectionelements for the second.

To correct this data, I tried with

```
UPDATE demand SET pub_refs = REPLACE (pub_refs, "ArrayCollection_elements', 'ArrayCollectionelements')
```

but this doesn't work because of special chars. Trying with

```
UPDATE demand SET pub_refs = REPLACE (pub_refs, "ArrayCollection�_elements', 'ArrayCollection�elements')
```

doesn't work better. How can I correct this data ?

Comment: This isn't a solution but a tip. You can better run the query on the Demand entity instead of the Event entity. The result will be an array of demands and then you don't need to iterate over the events to get the demands. It will simplify you method.

Answer (score 3):

Doctrine can populate results as an Array instead of an ArrayCollection, simply change the `getResult()` call to:

```
 $results = $query->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

This would be the most efficient way to complete your task however you could also use ArrayCollection's built-in `toArray()` method to convert its own data to array format:

```
 $publications = $results->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. My $results ans $result variables are already array, but $result['pubrefs'] is arrayCollection. When I try to convert it in array with this `$arrayPubs =$pubs->toArray()`, I get nothing in the array and have Invalid argument supplied for foreach() when I try to iterate on the array : .

Answer (score 0):

As the problem seems to be due to a change in the storage of ArrayCollection in database between 2.3 and 2.7 version of symfony, I created an line command to update these in database.